# Is there a way to make an app be classified in google play store or apple store?

Tags: android, ios, google-play, app-store

Restricting an app, allowed only for certain users who meet requirements.

We are planning to develop an app for Andriod and IOS users. Now we have some requirements for the users to meet before downloading the app in google play store or apple store.

First: the user should be registered on the (third party) website. Second: the user has paid a certain amount for the application.

So is there a way to do it? or any suggestions?

My suggestion is not to upload the app in the store. Upload the file app on the server. Then put a download link to the website. And when a user meets the requirements, they are allowed to view and download the app. What do you think?

Comment: You can upload your app to store (App Store, GG Play) and direct link from your website to the store link

Comment: @QuocNguyen it will be downloaded and installed by anyone who searches it on play store because it is public. Is there any option or setup on play store?